# Server overload ... with requests? How do I efficiently program server-client wise

Tags: javascript, sql-server

SO, I have a server with MySQL database in it, and a client (browser) that retrieves data from the server and displays to the user.

I'm struggling over whether I should let client get all the data he needs from a MySQL server (using PHP), and let client to do all querying, adding, updating to the data with JavaScript or other related library, and send it back to the server for the server to update his data; OR

whether I should let client send requests (query, add, update, etc) to the server with relevant parameters for server to handle the user's data with, say, MySQL commands.

I think first way could relief the server because all the work is done by the clients' computer, and not by the server, but would be hard for me to learn or make a library that does all the querying and stuff that can otherwise be done with MySQL commands which I find easier to work with at this moment.

And I think the second way would be easier for me, because I can just use PHP and MySQL to perform whatever server needs to do for client, but it makes me think that it would load server with too many repetitive work for each client if there were too many clients.

Which method is better?

At this moment, I'm the only client and server is run on the same computer, so there won't be too much load of commands that server would need to run, but I want to know which method is most canonical and efficient security, efficiency, etc wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both solutions have their pros and cons. If you have a huge set of data, you don't want to dump it all to the client, especially if they only need to view or modify a fraction of it. If any of your data needs to be protected against unwanted change (like a user increasing their access level, credit, etc) you can't place the logic on the client since that will be easy to hack. If neither is a concern, client-side logic may indeed take a lot of load off your database server.

There are client-side frameworks like Angular and React that make working with data easier, although they too have a learning curve. Check if they fit your needs.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I needed what the THING was called. Angular does that? I needed to learn that anyways. If I learned Angular before asking this question, I wouldn't have asked the question. Thanks for suggesting the framework. I'll give it a try as soon as possible.

Comment: Having said that, I think I made you answer like other answers on questions tagged with "subjective" or something like that. Sorry. But thanks for the suggestion anyways.